# Bootstrap-contextmenu with knockout

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm trying to use Bootstrap-contextmenu from https://github.com/sydcanem/bootstrap-contextmenu with knockout js. And i have a problem. How can i pass the selectedItem from my table to my viewModel. I have a simple code like that:

```
    <tr style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="context" data-target="#context-menu">
...

    <div id="context-menu"> <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-bind="event: { click: $root.editUser }">Edit</a> </li>
...
```

Command works but i didn't get a user from the clicked tr.

Maybe there is another context menu with knockout js support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like, i've found a solution - https://github.com/nescalante/knockout.contextmenu. It works right for my case.